# How to get only out of stock products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-collection, out-of-stock

How to get out of stock product collection using object manager.

I retrieve product collection

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->setPageSize(8)
            ->load();
```

but how to add out of stock condition to it.

> I have tried this solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138729/magento-2-get-out-of-stock-products-in-collection) but it does not work.

### EDIT

Executing Below code gives following error:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory
    ->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
    // use this if you want to filter by quantity = 0
    ->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', 'cataloginventory_stock_item.qty=0')
    // use this if you want to filter by is_in_stock = false
    ->joinField('is_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', 'cataloginventory_stock_item.is_in_stock=0')
    ->setPageSize(8)
    ->load();
```

**Error**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
 Unknown column 'at_qty.cataloginventory_stock_item.qty' in 'on clause' in D:\xa
mpp\htdocs\projects\magentoSite\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\State
ment\Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\magentoSite\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\
Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\magentoSite\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\M
ysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\magentoSite\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\
Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)

#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\magentoSite\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\
Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\magentoSite\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\
Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(
DI...', Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\proj in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\magentoSite\vendor\magento\zend
framework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 235
```

Comment: Go to http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/ And look for Search Criteria Section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory
    ->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', 'qty=0')
    ->setPageSize(8)
    ->load()
;
```

Comment: Filter by `status:STATUS_ENABLED` will give enabled product. I need Out of stock products

Comment: I have removed `addAttributeToFilter` and added `joinField` method call, does it work?

Comment: getting following error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
 Unknown column 'at_qty.cataloginventory_stock_item.stock_id' in 'on clause' in
D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\magentoSite\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\
Statement\Pdo.php:228

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the latest version of Magento 2? If yes, are you sure you have cataloginventory_stock_item table? It's created by magento/module-catalog-inventory module. I'm running Magento 2.1.2 and that code works like a charm.

Comment: Yes using Magento 2.1.2, and table is present in database

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have edited the join field, you may see the two joinField, one for filter by quantity = 0, and one for filter by is_in_stock.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate you help, but I am still getting error, I have updated my question with the error I am getting.

Comment: I have updated the code. It's filtered by `qty=0`. If you want to filter by `is_in_stock=0`, change the join field to `->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'is_in_stock=0')`. To be clear, use only one of the filters (`qty=0` OR `is_in_stock=0`), not both.

Comment: awesome, Finally...

Answer (score 4):

By default in product collection join the `cataloginventory_stock_status` table so `"stock_status_index.stock_status = 1"` added into the query.

To get the only out of stock products, first we need to remove `cataloginventory_stock_status` join and than filter again.

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create();
$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
$collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('from' => $start ,'to' => $end))->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku'))
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
->joinField('qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', array('stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
    ->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', ['eq' => 0])
->load();
```

Important part of this code is:

```
$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
```

Comment: this is working fine and  giving all out of stock  product including `Not Visible Individually`

Answer (score 1):

You will get full collection from your code so just find your out of stock Item using condition 
`if (!$_product->isSaleable())`
then print Product data,

Comment: it is not a wise option if store have lots products, it will consume to much computation time, I am looking for a better approch