# Magento 2 get all products including out of stock ones

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I have below code in an script outside Magento to get products. It's working fine except it doens't return out of stock products.

How can I add out of stock products to the collection?

```
// Only gets in stock products
public function getProductsInStock() {
    try {
        $productCollection = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

        $collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
            ->load();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

**EDIT:** I just did some testing. It seems it has to do with following option in backend: `Display Out of Stock Products`. When it is set to `yes` the code returns all products instead of just the `in stock` products.

Is it possible to ignore this setting in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection according your needs. You can use can use it to get product data :

**Option 2 :**
Also, You can try below code to get product collection, ( out side of magento ) though this is not best way

Update :

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)->load();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getSku() . "=>" . $product->getPrice();
}
```

Comment: Thx for suggestions. I just tried it out option 2. I doesn't return out of stock products either. Am I doing something wrong? Is there maybe something going wrong? Might this is a feature (backend setting, or so?).

Comment: I just did some testing. It has to do with following option in backend: `Display Out of Stock Products`. When it is set to `yes` the code returns all products instead of just the in stock products. Is it possible to ignore this setting in any way? I will update my question.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it will get you all products

Comment: @Akif, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Yes, it does work. But this needs refactoring of my code. Since it expects a collection. I am going to wait if someone comes up with a solution to just ignore this setting and still get a collection. Or maybe you have an idea?

Comment: @Akif, hope this will work for you, i have setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true), which will bypass stock filter and display all products ( in stock and out of stock )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75424/discussion-between-naveed-and-akif).

Comment: Last suggestion works! Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Similar to this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213906/63865

Answer (score 0):

```
$resource = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item');
    $select = $resource->getConnection()->select()->from($resource->getMainTable());
    $stockItems = $resource->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
    foreach($stockItems as $_item){
        var_dump($_item->getData());
    }
```

Please try this one may be it will help you